# Django Python Dropdown failing on submit

Tags: python, django, dropdown

Getting errors, when selecting dropdown and hit `Go To`. It looks like it is not POST value back and thru error.

Under View, If I add following it will get to second page, but without passing any value:

```
class GatherDataView(FormView):
    context_object_name = 'location'
    template_name = 'gatherdata.html'
    form_class = SelectSITEForm
```

It doesn't pass the value onclick submit button.

forms.py

```
class SelectSITEForm(forms.Form):

    LOCATIONS = (
        ('DC1', 'DC1'),
        ('DC2', 'DC2'),
    )
    location = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LOCATIONS, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SelectSITE
```

views.py

```
from .models import SelectSITE
from .forms import SelectSITEForm
class CheckView(FormView):

    template_name = "check.html"
    form_class = SelectSITEForm
class GatherDataView(FormView):

    def gatherdata(request):
        form = SelectSITEForm(request.POST or None)
        answer = ''
        if form.is_valid():
            location = form.cleaned_data.get('location')
        return render(request, 'gatherdata.html', {'form': form, 'location': location})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^navbar/', views.NavPageView.as_view()), 
    url(r'^check/', views.checkView.as_view()),
    url(r'^gatherdata/', views.GatherDataView.as_view(), name='gatherdata'), 
]
```

html

```
<form method="post" action = "{% url 'gatherdata' %}"> {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="fieldWrapper" align="center" id="mainselection">
    <select name="location">
      <option selected>Select an the site</option>
      {% for val in form.location %}
      <option value="{{ val }}"></option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
  <button align="center" class="button execute" name="submit" value="submit">GO TO</button></form>
```

onclick submit button HTML

```
{% extends "check.html" %}
{% block content %}
<br><br><br>
<h1>{{ location }}</h1>
```

Traceback:

```
URL: http://dpaste.com/3A0TFDS
Exception Type: TypeError at /gatherdata/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: what is output of **print(form.is_valid())**

Comment: I added the print statement above the `def gatherdata(request):` which it print, but after that it show error
```
   return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
   [19/Jul/2019 15:55:20] "POST /gatherdata/ HTTP/1.1" 500 80313
```

Comment: I'm getting `false` which doesn't get to if statement.